# Is there any algorithm that allows me to identify if a photo was taken from the image being shown on a display?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm working on a service that prompts the user to upload photos taken with the camera phone. An example would be to ask the user for a picture of the apple he is eating at the moment. Some users try to cheat the service by taking, for example, a photo of their computer screen displaying an apple. Sometimes we can see the frame of the screen in the photo and sometimes we realize because the photo seems pixelated or one can notice the edges of the navigation window (user uploads a photo from a Google image search photo). Is there any algorithm that allows me to identify if the user is taking an "original" picture or taking it of a display screen?

Comment: You could check the EXIF data to make sure the picture was taken when you asked for it. EXIF data can be faked of course, but most people wouldn’t think of doing that, or wouldn’t know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is known as **recaptured image detection** or **liveness detection** if the subject of the photo is a person.

I am not aware of any libraries implementing the former, but here are some papers on the topic:

- [Single-view recaptured image detection based on physics-based features](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/dvmm/publications/10/SRIDBPF_ICME2010.pdf)
- [Recaptured photo detection using specularity distribution](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ttng/recapturing-project/icip08-recaptured-photo-detection.pdf)
- [Identification of recaptured photographs on LCD screens](http://rose1.ntu.edu.sg/datasets/RecaptureImages/LCD_Recaptured_Cao2010.pdf)
- [Classification of captured and recaptured images to detect photograph spoofing](http://www.eurecom.fr/fr/publication/3646/download/mm-publi-3646.pdf)
- [Image recapture detection using multiple features](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.396.737&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Is there any implementation or library. Because I can't find any.